# Drop PostgreSql DB from php

Tags: php, postgresql, database-permissions

Is there any way to write `DROP DATABASE [ IF EXISTS ] name` from php script? Seems that I need something similar to `mysql_drop_db` just for Postrge.

How my `$connStr` in `$conn = pg_connect($connStr)` must look like to have rights to do this command? What db I must be connected?

Comment: `DROP DATABASE` is a query so you can use `pg_query($conn, 'DROP DATABASE')`

Comment: Should I always set db name in pgconnect? How my  $connStr in  $conn = pg_connect($connStr) must look like? Should I connect to db which I want to drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to be connected to a different db on same cluster as superuser role or db owner

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropdatabase.html

> It can only be executed by the database owner. Also, it cannot be
>   executed while you or anyone else are connected to the target
>   database. (Connect to postgres or any other database to issue this
>   command.)

2. Have to `pg_terminate_backend(pid)` other connections on the db you want to drop before you drop it:

   `select pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
   from pg_stat_activity 
   where pid <> pg_backend_pid() and datname = 'db_to_drop';`

Comment: So I can drop one database while I connected to the ANY other... Thanks, I will try